# Storybook build success but error when serving

Tags: storybook

I have encountered a problem when serving a built storybook. As you can see below, it shows only a spinner spinning into oblivion. When i opened the console, it says:
`Error: manager  received sharedStateChanged-manager-storybook/viewport but was unable to determine the source of the event`

[image: empty spinner]

Here's my storybook configuration files:

`main.js`

```
module.exports = {
  stories: [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app"
  ],
  webpackFinal: config => {
    return {
      ...config,
      plugins: config.plugins.filter(plugin => {
        if (plugin.constructor.name === 'ESLintWebpackPlugin') {
          return false
        }
        return true
      }),
    }
  }
}
```

`preview.js`

```
import '../src/recore/.storybook/preview.css'
import * as Recore from '../src/recore'

Recore.init({
  defaults: {
    IMAGE_RESOLVER: path => {
      return import('../src/assets/' + path)
    }
  }
})

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
}
```

To build the storybook, i run `build-storybook -o ./build -s ./public -c .storybook`
I am using npm, and it told me to do `npm run build-storybook -- -o ...` but it doesn't behave as expected. Also, I currently use `"@storybook/react": "^6.1.21"`

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Can you help me to fix it?
Many thanks before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.2.9",

https://gist.github.com/shilman/8856ea1786dcd247139b47b270912324

Comment: This didn't seem to fix the error for me. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 7):

When I had this problem I was starting the static file serving with `npx serve -s`.

Changing the startup to `npx serve` fixed the problem (this was hosting on a Linux web app in Azure).

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to deploy it to Amplify you need to rewrite some rules: (top to bottom)

1st rule: `Source: /iframe.html    Target: /iframe.html`

2nd rule: `Source: /<*>    Target: /index.html`

3rd rule: `Source: </^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|xml|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>    Target: /index.html`

Be aware that the 1st rule the target is to **iframe.html**

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to deploy it to amplify?

Comment: Nope, i was trying to deploy it into GCP

Comment: @Gabriel Mičko, I'm having this issue on amplify.  Any idea how to mitigate?

Comment: @twinlakes I think it was a server configuration problem that amplify did not serve some .html file. If I remember correctly I fixed it by enabling html to be served, not just index.html. If that doesn't help lmk I can take a look.

Comment: Yes, amplify adds some rewrite/redirect rules that need to be deleted first.  This is why it has the same repro as @Bazza's answer.

Comment: Hi @GabrielMičko I am facing the same error.. I added all of the above, but this amplify still won't show storybook on my FE. Any chance to chat in private and try to fix this?

Comment: In my case it was problem with iframe.html being blocked as well. The suggestion above should work. If it doesn’t you can DM me on Twitter. @MilošMilutinov

Answer (score 1):

I only needed 1 rule in my Amplify config to get storybook to work

Note the below is from terraform, but you should be able to grok it's meaning:

```
  custom_rule {
    source = "</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(html|css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$)([^.]+$)/>"
    status = "200"
    target = "/index.html"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For **AWS AMPLIFY**

Source address: /iframe.html
Target address: /iframe.html
Type: 200 (Rewrite)

Source address: /<*>
Target address: /index.html
Type: 404 (Redirect)

Source address: </^[^.]+$|.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|map|json|xlsx)$)([^.]+$)/>
Target address: /index.html
Type: 200 (Rewrite)

[how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fHih.png)